# Angular UI-Grid tree level with different templates

Tags: treeview, angular-ui-grid

I'm new here, I'm working with Angular UI-Grid, and I have a small problem. The grid that I handle has a tree structure, that works perfect. But to make it easier to follow that structure for the user, I want to implement different colors per level.

I have created this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lZhsWAcR8uh73vqn99CE?p=preview) with two examples, the first is how you should see the different colors per level, and the second is how it behaves today. Has anyone done something like this or do you have any idea how to fix it?

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid','ui.grid.treeView']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','uiGridTreeViewConstants', function ($scope, $http, uiGridTreeViewConstants) {

  $scope.myData = [
    {"ubi_id":321,"ubi_nom":"America","ubi_pad_id":null,"ubi_tip_id":1,"$$treeLevel":0},
    {"ubi_id":322,"ubi_nom":"Sudamerica","ubi_pad_id":321,"ubi_tip_id":2,"$$treeLevel":1},
    ...
    ];

  var rowtpl = '';
  rowtpl += '<div ng-class="{\'nivelGrilla-{{row.entity.$$treeLevel}}\': row.entity.$$treeLevel != \'undefined\' }">';
  rowtpl += '<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name"';
  rowtpl +=   'class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell>';
  rowtpl += '</div></div>';

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data:'myData',
    rowTemplate:rowtpl,
  };

}]);
```

css:

```
.nivelGrilla-0{
  background-color: #254158;
  color: white;
}

.nivelGrilla-1{
  background-color: #3F6F96;
  color: white;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-tree-view class="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Looks great, what problem?

Comment: @Jeb50 When the levels are opened one by one (in the second grid), the row class is not refreshed, so the level effect is lost

Comment: have you tried [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/)? I too got frustrated using ui-grid because many options/features not documented, some documented are not detailed enough to get a clue, some even not working in Plunker. I decided to give this ag-grid a shot.

Comment: @Jeb50 I finally found a solution, I will consider ag-grid, thank you very much anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, the div that contains the entire row, makes a call to a function that returns the name of the class according to the row level.

[Here's a plnkr with my solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/2VWpri1BCntTrLjaWZ98?p=preview)

js:

```
    var rowtpl = '';
      rowtpl += '<div class=\"{{grid.appScope.rowLevel(row)}}\">';
      rowtpl += '<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name"';
      rowtpl +=   'class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell>';
      rowtpl += '</div>';
      rowtpl += '</div>';

  $scope.gridOptions2 = {
    data:'myData',
    rowTemplate:rowtpl,
  };
```

css:

```
.ui-grid-row .ui-grid-cell {
   background-color: inherit !important;
   color: inherit !important;
}

.ui-grid-row .ui-grid-cell.ui-grid-cell {
    background-color: #f0f0ee;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #d4d4d4;
}

.rowLevel-0{
  background-color: #254158;
  color: white;
}

.rowLevel-1{
  background-color: #3F6F96;
  color: white;
}
.rowLevel-2{
  background-color: #5289B6;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a 'cellClass' within your grid's 'columnDefs' and switch the rows according to the tree level. For example:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
data:'myData',
columnDefs: [
  { field: 'Id', name: 'Ubi Id'},
  { field: 'Country', name: 'Ubi Nom'},
    cellClass: function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
    switch(row.treeLevel)
    {
      case 0:
      return 'red';

      case 1:
      return 'blue';

      case 2:
      return 'green';

      default:
      break;
    }
  }
]
};
```